# Whois Response issues

Tags: linux, bash, domain, whois

Ok trying to work this out and getting confused. I am using the whois command and getting responses from the registrar server ie :

```
whois google.com
```

this returns for the expirys :

```
Created on..............: 1997-09-15.
Expires on..............: 2020-09-13.
Record last updated on..: 2012-01-29.
```

This is great but I also need the Status of the domain

for example if you goto

```
http://www.who.is/whois/google.com
```

I get this info

```
Status: clientDeleteProhibited, clientTransferProhibited, clientUpdateProhibited, serverDeleteProhibited, serverTransferProhibited, serverUpdateProhibited

Expiration Date: 2020-09-14
Creation Date: 1997-09-15
Last Update Date: 2011-07-20
```

The difference is this extra status item, How can I get that using a whois command??

Comment: This is what I get: `Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited
   Updated Date: 30-mar-2012
   Creation Date: 31-mar-2004
   Expiration Date: 31-mar-2013

>>> Last update of whois database: Mon, 06 Aug 2012 14:30:29 UTC <<<`

Comment: can you confirm what whois server that uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every registrar has its own output format.  If you query a registrar who does not provide this information, it cannot be obtained (at least not using the whois protocol).

For your particular example of `google.com` this information is maintained by the top-level registrar at `whois.internic.net`, though.  Apparently your particular `whois` client is not displaying the output from `whois.internic.net`.  From mine, I get a lengthy result from `whois.internic.net` (including information about registry entries beginning with `google.com.` which there are several dozen, some of them rather embarrassing) before the information for this particular domain from its registrar.

I'd recommend writing a simple `whois` client of your own if you really need to see exactly what is going on.  `telnet whois.internic.net 43` and type in `=google.com` for a good start.